# In the ring of polynomials $F[t]$, every ideal is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

Let

$$\langle a \rangle=\bigcap_{ a \in I} I$$

$$ \langle a \rangle =\{ Ira + na, r\in R,n \in Z\}$$

What is unclear is why$$ I=\langle 0 \rangle$$ proves that I is a principal ideal. My definition of principal ideal is given.

Comment: Principal, not principle.

Comment: No idea what that triangle with the line under it means.

Comment: @Thomas I think it probably is meaning to say that $I$ is an ideal. It looks like the normal subgroup notation.

Comment: Yup , it means that I is an ideal

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by $\langle a \rangle = \{ Ira+ na, r \in R, n \in Z \}$.  Why the $I$ there?

Comment: I don;t know to be honest, lets say that means elements of I, in one notebook that is given, in another one not, so i'm guessing the question is workable without it/

Comment: Another thing:  you write $\langle a \rangle = \bigcap I$,  $a \subseteq I$; perhaps you meant $a \in I$, since $a \in  R$ is a single element, whereas $I$ is a *subset* of $R$.  Cheers!

Comment: Help, don't leave so abruptly, an answer is no where in sight !

Comment: Upvote this , like charity, i need help.

Comment: If you answer my last question, maybe I can say more!  Cheers!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is meant, by what was formerly typed.

Comment: Bozo Vulicevic -"Cheers!"

Comment: I'm editing your question based on what you said.  Cheers!

Comment: Where does the polynomial ring $F[t]$ enter in to this question?